# group by and merge some field result in linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq, group-by

I have a class like

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a list of this class: `List<Person> persons`;

```
var persons = new List<Person> {
            new Person { Id = 1, LastName = "Reza", FirstName="Jenabi" },
            new Person { Id = 1, LastName = "Amin", FirstName="Golmahalle"},
            new Person { Id = 2, LastName = "Hamed", FirstName="Naeemaei"}
        };
```

Is there a way I can group by `Id` and get the list of all the full Name (Combine first and last names)?

So after grouping:

```
var Id = results[0].Id; // Output : 1
List<string> fullNames = results[0].FullNames; // Output : "Reza Jenabi","Amin Golmahalle"
```

Comment: `persons.GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(x => String.Join(", ", x.Select(a => $"{a.FirstName} {a.LastName}"));`

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev:  I would get list of fullNames

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is what you need:

```
var results = persons.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
    .Select(x => new { Id = x.Key, FullNames = x.Select(p => $"{p.FirstName} {p.LastName}").ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think bellow code can help you:

```
var fff = from p in persons
        group $"{p.FirstName} {p.LastName}" by p.Id into g
        select new { PersonId = g.Key, FullNames = g.ToList() };
```

Answer (score 0):

yeah, you can use `GroupBy` and `Join` those items:

```
var grouped = persons.GroupBy(p => p.Id)
    .Select(s => string.Join(", ", s.Select(a=> $"{a.FirstName} {a.LastName}")));
```